# DB query or logic optimization needed

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, database-performance

I am executing below query (oracle11g) on 2 millions records. It is taking ~2.2 seconds.

my query :

```
select SUBSCRIBER_NUM, SUBSCRIBER_STATUS, P_ID
from C_S_FORWARD_INFO
where '07052620' LIKE SUBSCRIBER_NUM || '%'
  and SCP_VER = 1
```

Below is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE C_S_FORWARD_INFO 
  ( 
    SUBSCRIBER_NUM                  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
    P_ID                            NUMBER, 
  SUBSCRIBER_STATUS NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER                  INTEGER NOT NULL,   
    MAJOR_VERSION_ID                NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, 
    MINOR_VERSION_ID             NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, 
    SCP_VER                         NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 CHECK (SCP_VER IN (0,1)), 
  );

ALTER TABLE C_S_FORWARD_INFO ADD CONSTRAINT C_S_FORWARD_INFO_PK
PRIMARY KEY (SUBSCRIBER_NUM,ACCOUNT_NUMBER,MAJOR_VERSION_ID, MINOR_VERSION_ID);
```

DB Records ( for example, in real it has 2 millions records)

```
Row 1 => 07052620,1,1,10, 1, 1, 1;
Row 2 => 0705262,2,1,10, 1, 1, 1;
Row 3 => 070526,3,1,10, 1, 1, 1;
Row 4 => 070526200001,4, 1,10, 1, 1, 1;
Row 5 => 07052,5,1,10, 1, 1, 1;
......
```

expected result : Row 1 ( i am getting this by above query , logic : begin with longest match till '07052620')

How can i optimize above query. Or write any other logic to get expected result in `.2` seconds. In my query '07052620' is dynamic number getting as a input in stored procedure.

20/11 - Update :

I tried below ( VAR_CALLING_NUM = 07052620):

```
while var1<=len LOOP 
temp1 := SUBSTR(VAR_CALLING_NUM, 1, var1); 
temp1 := concat('''',temp1); 
temp1 := concat(temp1,''''); 
temp6 := temp6 || temp1 || ',' ; 
var1:=var1+1; 
END LOOP; 
temp6 := SUBSTR(temp6, 1,length(temp6)-1);

select SUBSCRIBER_NUM, SUBSCRIBER_STATUS, P_ID from C_S_FORWARD_INFO where SUBSCRIBER_NUM IN ( temp6 ) and SCP_VER = 1 order by length(subscriber_num) desc;
```

But this is not giving me result. Looks like query is not taking temp6 dynamically. Please help

Comment: Your current query has a logical problem and in addition you have an optimization problem.  Which one do you want solved?

Comment: What proportion of the rows in the table do you expect to meet these conditions?

Comment: Also, how many unique values are there for the subscriber number in the data set, and how varied by the input number be? Could it be "0"? Or will it always be at least so-many characters?

Comment: @ David Aldridge : Query should give me row 1, 2 , 3, and row 5.It should not give me row 4. Currently it is giving no record. I suspect that temp6 which i m passing dynamically in 'IN' , query is not taking that.  However , temp6 is "'0', '07', '070', '0705', '07052', '070526', '0705262', '07052620'". But not sure if query is taking it dynamically or not, may be i am doing some mistake  ( SUBSCRIBER_NUM IN ( temp6 )). Please help.

Comment: In real cases input number will not be 0. It can be of 30 digits max. However, there is no min limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your query:

```
select SUBSCRIBER_NUM, SUBSCRIBER_STATUS, P_ID
from C_S_FORWARD_INFO
where '07052620' LIKE SUBSCRIBER_NUM || '%' and
      SCP_VER = 1;
```

Then, I would suggest rewriting it as:

```
select SUBSCRIBER_NUM, SUBSCRIBER_STATUS, P_ID
from C_S_FORWARD_INFO
where SUBSCRIBER_NUM IN ('0', '07', '070', '0705', '07052', '070526', '0705262', '07052620') and
      SCP_VER = 1
order by length(subscriber_num) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Then, add an index on `(SCP_VER, SUBSCRIBER_NUM)`:

```
create index idx_forwardinfo_2 on c_s_forward_info(SCP_VER, SUBSCRIBER_NUM);
```

Comment: Thanks but this number ( 07052620 ) can be of 30 digits so in query we will be having 30 combination in 'IN'

Comment: Requesting your input please

Comment: @VJS . . . That is okay.  Oracle should still use the index.

Comment: I tried below ( VAR_CALLING_NUM = 07052620): while var1<=len LOOP
    temp1 := SUBSTR(VAR_CALLING_NUM, 1, var1);
     temp1 := concat('''',temp1);
     temp1 := concat(temp1,'''');
     temp6 := temp6 || temp1 || ',' ;  
     var1:=var1+1;
    END LOOP;
      temp6 := SUBSTR(temp6, 1,length(temp6)-1);
     select SUBSCRIBER_NUM, SUBSCRIBER_STATUS, P_ID
from C_S_FORWARD_INFO
where SUBSCRIBER_NUM IN ( temp6 ) and SCP_VER = 1
order by length(subscriber_num) desc;  But this is not giving me result. Looks like query is not taking temp6 dynamically. Please help.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff : Added in Question as well what i tried. Requesting you to please help.

Answer (score 0):

The following query adds a subquery to your original attempt which restricts results to those which match but also restricts to the longest match.  It returns a single record arbitrarily, but it can easily be modified if you wanted to return ties for longest match.

```
select SUBSCRIBER_NUM,
       SUBSCRIBER_STATUS,
       P_ID
from C_S_FORWARD_INFO
where '07052620' LIKE SUBSCRIBER_NUM || '%'  and
      SCP_VER = 1 and
LENGTH(SUBSCRIBER_NUM) = (select max(length(SUBSCRIBER_NUM)) from C_S_FORWARD_INFO
                          where '07052620' like SUBSCRIBER_NUM || '%' and SCP_VER = 1)
offset 0 rows fetch next 1 rows only;
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try. Just one thing, i am new to databases, how can i add index to SUBSCRIBER_NUM column. Any query need to run ? Sorry if you find it wired question.

Comment: Should i execute : CREATE INDEX C_S_FORWARD_INFO_IDX ON C_S_FORWARD_INFO (SUBSCRIBER_NUM) for index

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : I am not getting expected result using your query.Case : If Row 1 is not present in DB then my expected result is Row 2  as 0705262 is the longest begin with match. Can you please see. Using your query, i am getting Row 4 which is not expeected.

Comment: If you really only want the first record, then what is the point of a wildcard?  Just use equals.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  : I need begin with longest match. Through equal it is not possible. In query we have "where '07052620' " so my expected row selection are  0, 07, 070, 0705, 07052, 070526, 0705262, 07052620 and as 07052620  is the longest match, i will select this one.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : Now your query is giving me expected result but it is taking ~2.5 secs over 2 million records.

Comment: @VJS You changed your question midway.  I don't think you can use an index for this `LIKE` clause.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : Sorry about that but my intention was the same when i asked the question. Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not aid your performance issue:

```
WITH pred_vals AS (SELECT SUBSTR('07052620', 1, LENGTH('07052620') + 1 - LEVEL) str,
                          LEVEL priority
                   FROM   dual
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('07052620')),
     main_join AS (SELECT fi.subscriber_num,
                          fi.subscriber_status,
                          fi.p_id
                          row_number() OVER (ORDER BY pv.priority) rn
                   FROM   c_s_forward_info fi
                          INNER JOIN pred_vals pv ON (fi.subscriber_num = pv.str)
                   WHERE  scp_ver = 1)
SELECT subscriber_num,
       subscriber_status,
       p_id
FROM   main_join
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

I would suggest that you have a multi-column index on c_s_forward_info on the following columns: (subscriber_num, scp_ver, subscriber_status, p_id)

That should hopefully allow the query to run against just the index.

The query works by first breaking the string you're passing down into the various combinations that you want to match again (which is the first N characters in the string, where N is anything between 1 and the length of the string being passed in).

Once we have these strings to match to, we can do a straight join on them to the subscriber column, which will allow the optimizer to use an index if it deems it is more efficient to do so.

Then, we can calculate the row_number() (or maybe dense_rank() if you want to display all rows that match to the highest priority joined rows) and then select the top row(s).